# How to get the hight value for multidimensional array

Tags: php

I have the following multidimensional array:

```
array(
    array(
        [id] => 65,
        [user_id] => 1,
        [total] => 1
    ),
    array(
        [id] => 66,
        [user_id] => 3,
        [total] => 2
    ),
    array(
        [id] => 67,
        [user_id] => 5,
        [total] => 4
    ),
)
```

How do I get the array with the highest value for total and I still get the full key Value for the array like this:

```
array(
    [id] => 67,
    [user_id] => 5,
    [total] => 4
)
```

Comment: Use [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to put the desired item on the first position then get it from there.

Comment: @stedape: you should really accept one of the many correct answers, don't you think? or didn't they help you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$total = array();
foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
    $total[$key]  = $row['total'];
}

// this sorts your $data array by `total` in descending order
// so the max for `total` is the first element
array_multisort($total, SORT_DESC, $data);
```

And now, use `$data[0]`;

Answer (score 0):

Order the arrays on id using `usort()`:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($b["id"], $a["id"]);
}
usort($arr, 'cmp'); // $arr is your array
```

Then the first array has your desired values.

See the documentation on usort for more information: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: It's my favorite ! No fuss no muss.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = [
    ['id' => 1, 'total' => 1],
    ['id' => 2, 'total' => 4],
    ['id' => 3, 'total' => 5],
];

function cmp($a, $b) {
    return ($a['total'] < $b['total']) ? 1 : -1;
}

usort($array, 'cmp');

print_r($array[0]); // output ['id' => 3, 'total' => 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_column()` with `array_search()`:

```
$totals = array_column( $array, 'total' );
$result = $array[ array_search( max( $totals ), $totals ) ];
```

`array_column()` return an array with 'total' values. Use it to retrieve the key of main array with max total value.

But... what about following array?

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'id' => 65,
        'user_id' => 1,
        'total' => 4
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 66,
        'user_id' => 3,
        'total' => 2
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 67,
        'user_id' => 5,
        'total' => 4
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 68,
        'user_id' => 6,
        'total' => 2
    )
);
```

To filter **all** max values, you can use this:

```
$max = max( array_column( $array, 'total' ) );
$result = array_filter
(
    $array,
    function( $row ) use ( $max )
    {
        return $row['total'] == $max;
    }
);
print_r( $result );
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 65
            [user_id] => 1
            [total] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 67
            [user_id] => 5
            [total] => 4
        )

)
```

Put in `$max` variable max value of 'total' column, then use it to filter original array and retrieve all rows having it as total.

---

- Read more about [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)
- Read more about [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Answer (score -2):

You can install xdebug for var_dump 
and look you array by

```
var_dump($array);
```

after you can get needing array by key

```
$array[3]; //example for question context
```

or get by `foreach` for analyses you array

```
$arrayResult = array();
foreach($array as $_arr) {
   if($_arr['user_id'] == 5) {
      $arrayResult = $_arr;
   }
}
var_dump($arrayResult);
```

this is example for your question context too

Comment: this doesnt answer the question. if he already knew, that the 3rd item with the user_id=5 has the highest value, he wouldn't ask for that!?

Comment: If he knew that 3 element is user_id 5 then he knew that 3 element get by `$array[3]` he don't know how to get this element how to he can knew what 3 key is user_id = 5 if array can change evrytime, if adding user or edited when $array exist 4 or 5 elements and user_id = 5 maybe can and 3 element and 4 and 5 any elements....

Comment: sorry, I have no clue what you are saying. punctuation is your friend!

Comment: @jeff I'm Russian :D and bad speak English only understand. I just say that, he can not get element 3 in array, how to he can knew that element 3 this is id=67 for example.